# Get the details of all Indian films from Wikipedia

Tags: linked-data, film, wikidata

My application needs the details of All Indian movies. I can't take it from IMDB or OMDB because the number of Indian movies is too less there. I need to fetch it from Wikipedia. Freebase is deprecated now and I have heard DBPedia has many less entries. The only option left is Wikidata's query API. But it is getting too tough to form the query. Couldn't understand through Wikidata's 1 page api documentation. Tried the following query, but it returned just 2118 entries, which is too less compared to what we can see in Wikipedia (10000+) entries.

```
https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[31:(TREE[11424][][279])]%20AND%20tree[668][150][17,131]
```

Can anybody help me in fetching the details of all Indian movies from wikipedia? It would be a great help

Comment: You can use the Wikipedia database dumps, which are downloaded once and easier to parse than live-scraping https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html

Answer (score 3):

You can get all Wikidata items which are:

- [instance of](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31) (P31): [film](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11424) (Q11424)
- [origin from](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P495) (P495): [India](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q668) (Q668)

with the following SPARQL [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Movies%20made%20in%20India%0ASELECT%20%3Fmovie%20%3FmovieLabel%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%3Fmovie%20wdt%3AP495%20wd%3AQ668%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?movie ?movieLabel  WHERE {
   ?movie wdt:P495 wd:Q668 ;
          wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

The query returns 26,007 movies in 2022 (up from 21,595 entries when the original answer was written in 2015).